# Why Must I Cast Away Protocol Conformance on Swift Class for Array Extension?

Tags: swift

I am implementing a tree model. Each node type can have a wide selection of capabilities. I am implementing this with a base `class Node {}`, then many protocols, with default implementations, to describe the capabilities. I then have final classes, derived from Node, and conforming to some list of protocols, to describe my structure.

Each protocol has associated code in the following style:

```
protocol Protocol {}

typealias ProtocolConformingNode = Node & Protocol

extension Node
{
    public var isProtocolConforming: Bool {
        return asProtocolConforming != nil
    }

    public var asProtocolConforming: ProtocolConformingNode? {
        return self as? ProtocolConformingNode
    }
}
```

I use `Node & Protocol` so that I can use other protocol related queries on the returned items, e.g. `asOtherProtocolConforming`.

This all works fine, until I am dealing with arrays of `ProtocolConformingNode`. Initially I ran into problems filtering arrays of nodes + protocol, where I wanted to maintain the conformance after the filtering:

```
extension Array where Element: Node
{
    var someFilter: [Element] {
        return self
    }
}

let array = [ProtocolConformingNode]()
let filteredArray = array.someFilter
```

This gives the following error:

```
[ProtocolConformingNode]' (aka 'Array<Node & Protocol>') requires that 'ProtocolConformingNode' conform to 'AnyObject'
```

That felt a bit weird, but I think it falls under an issue discussed before on SO: [Protocol doesn't conform to itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33112559/protocol-doesnt-conform-to-itself)

I decided that type-erasing all my protocols would be too much for the rare cases I used this, so I would be content with casting my nodes after filtering. Note that I am not using `Element` in the following code, but explicitly using `Node`, and `Element == Node`:

```
extension Array where Element == Node
{
    var someFilter: [Node] {
        return self
    }
}

let array = [ProtocolConformingNode]()
let filteredArray = array.someFilter as! [ProtocolConformingNode]
```

This now gives the error:

```
'[ProtocolConformingNode]' (aka 'Array<Node & Protocol>') is not convertible to 'Array<Node>'
```

Which feels strange to me. I can get this to work like this:

```
let filteredArray = (array as [Node]).someFilter as! [ProtocolConformingNode]
```

But why do I have to cast here? How is it that the below works?

```
var nodes = [Node]()
var protocolConformingNodes = [ProtocolConformingNode]()
nodes.append(contentsOf: protocolConformingNodes)
```

When:

```
mutating func append<S>(contentsOf newElements: S) where Element == S.Element, S : Sequence
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the same issue as the SO post you linked. In particular, you should read Hamish's answer. IMO, this is a shortcoming of the language that should only be a problem if `Protocol` has static or initializer requirements, which in this case, it does not.

The quick and dirty fix is to use `@objc`. The full code would look like

```swift
class Node {}

@objc protocol Protocol {}

typealias ProtocolConformingNode = Node & Protocol

extension Array where Element: Node
{
    var someFilter: [Element] {
        return self
    }
}

let array = [ProtocolConformingNode]()
let filteredArray = array.someFilter // Yay! No error this time.
```